# MySQL Join Query to Sum a Field in One Table based on Its Corresponding Login ID in another Table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table `comment` with the following fields:

```
loginid submissionid points
```

I have a MySQL table called `submission` with the following fields:

```
loginid submissionid
```

For a given `submissionid`, the `loginid` in the two tables represent different things and therefore do nor correspond.

I would like a join to sum up `points` by `loginid`.  However, not by the `loginid` in `comment`, but rather the loginid in `submission`.  The connection between the two tables is made via the `submissionid`

I can't get this to work.  Below is what I have so far.  I'm trying to get this desired sum for each loginid pulled from another, third table, which is what the `l.loginid` represents.

How can I do this?

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT C2.submissionid, C2.loginid SUM(points) AS total 
    FROM comment C2
    INNER JOIN submission S2
    ON S2.submissionid = C2.submissionid
    GROUP BY C2.submissionid
) cscs ON cscs.loginid = l.loginid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT S2.loginid, SUM(points) AS total 
FROM submission S2
INNER JOIN comment C2
ON S2.submissionid = C2.submissionid
GROUP BY S2.loginid
```

This will give you a points sum for each loginid in the submission table.

Comment: Looks good, but it doesn't seem to be working.  The field "points" is not in the submission table, so can submission still be after FROM ?

Comment: `points` should work as long as it is a column in exactly one table in the join, or you could write it as `C2.points` if you prefer.

Comment: It only works with `SUM(C2.points)`... but it works.  Awesome, thanks.

Comment: I guess you must also have a points column in one of the other tables that you haven't shown that is conflicting with it.